# RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-2'

Tags: python, многопоточность, tkinter, asyncio

Создаю 2 потока. В одном отрисовывается окно tkinter, во втором asyncio устанавливает соединение с сервером и получает команды от него. Второй поток вылетает с ошибкой после попытки создать

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
```

В чем может быть проблема?
Клиент = https://pastebin.com/EEBCfMNq

```
C:\Users\Aleksey>py D:\Python\Сервер_Proj\new_client.py
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Aleksey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Aleksey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "D:\Python\Сервер_Proj\new_client.py", line 85, in client
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
  File "C:\Users\Aleksey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 678, in get_event_loop
    return get_event_loop_policy().get_event_loop()
  File "C:\Users\Aleksey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 584, in get_event_loop
    % threading.current_thread().name)
RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-2'.
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Из [документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloops.html#event-loop-policy-interface):

> The default policy defines context as the current thread, and manages
>   an event loop per thread that interacts with asyncio. If the current
>   thread doesn’t already have an event loop associated with it, the
>   default policy’s get_event_loop() method creates one when called from
>   the main thread, but raises RuntimeError otherwise.

По-русски говоря, первый вызов `asyncio.get_event_loop()` создаёт новый цикл событий только в главном потоке, а в любом другом выбрасывает исключение. Поэтому придётся создать его самому:

```
loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
```