# RuntimeWarning: включите tracemalloc, чтобы получить трассировку выделения объекта, как исправить?

Tags: python, многопоточность, pyqt5, asyncio

Работаю с `PyQt5`. Делаю приложение для логирования. Возникает проблема с потоком и `asyncio`.

При нажатии на кнопку должна запуститься асинхронная функция, которая получает через условия в постоянном цикле файлы на проверку и выводит полученные данные.

Асинхронная функция, которую я вызываю через поток:

```
async def deathcount():
    PLAYER_DEATH = '.*?Got character ZDOID from (\w+) : 0:0'
    log = "c:/.../files/log.txt"
    while True:     
        with open(log, encoding='utf-8', mode='r') as f:
            f.seek(0,2)
            while True:
                line = f.readline()
                if(re.search(PLAYER_DEATH, line)):
                    pname = re.search(PLAYER_DEATH, line).group(1)
                    with open(file, 'a', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as dl:
                        ... ...
                        log(f"{gettime}{pname} умер!")
                await asyncio.sleep(0.2)
```

**`PLAYER_DEATH`** - переменная, хранящая в себе строчку с регулярным выражением.
В постоянном цикле проверяется **log.txt**, на наличие строки из **PLAYER_DEATH**.

При нажатии на кнопку должна сработать функция `deathcount()`, которая в итоге, при положительном ответе, должна вывести результат - `log(f"{gettime}{pname} умер!")`

---

Результат выводится с помощью потока, там же и вызываем функцию (**`deathcount()`**):
**`basic.py`**:

```
class QTextEditLogger(logging.Handler):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__()

        self.PVELogs = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(parent.centralwidget)
        self.PVELogs.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 50, 801, 491))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Consolas")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.PVELogs.setFont(font)
        self.PVELogs.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(30, 30, 30); color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.PVELogs.setReadOnly(True)
        self.PVELogs.setPlainText("")
        self.PVELogs.setObjectName("PVELogs")

    def emit(self, record):
        msg = self.format(record)
        self.PVELogs.appendPlainText(msg)

class PVP(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, QWidget, MainInterface):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self) #init gui

        # logging
        logTextBox = QTextEditLogger(self)
        #logTextBox.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(f'{gettime}%(message)s'))
        logging.getLogger().addHandler(logTextBox)
        logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

        root_logger= logging.getLogger()
        root_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        handler = logging.FileHandler('PVPLog.log', 'w', 'utf-8') 
        handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(name)s, %(asctime)s, [%(levelname)s], %(message)s'))
        root_logger.addHandler(handler)

        self.PVELogs.setTextInteractionFlags(QtCore.Qt.TextSelectableByMouse) 

        self.thread = WorkThread()
        self.thread.threadSignal.connect(self.func2)           
        self.onPVE.clicked.connect(self.func1)      

    def func1(self):
        self.thread.start()

    def func2(self, value):
        deathcount() # Вызываем функцию ! ! !

class WorkThread(QtCore.QThread):
    threadSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):     
        for i in range(10):
            self.msleep(200)
            self.threadSignal.emit(i)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = PVP()
    mw.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec())
    
loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
loop.create_task(deathcount())
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
```

В конце файла создал новый цикл событий, советуясь [данной темы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/787715/runtimeerror-there-is-no-current-event-loop-in-thread-thread-2/787832#787832)

---

В конце асинхронной функции стоит ожидание (`await asyncio.sleep(0.2)`).
Но в итоге всё равно что-то не так.

```
c:\..\..\..\programma\basic.py:132: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'deathcount' was never awaited
  deathcount()
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

Попробовал вызвать цикл в самой функции `func2`:

```
def func2(self, value):
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    loop.create_task(deathcount())
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
```

Уже другой результат, так ещё в приложение появились интересные строчки:

```
C:\Users\Stepan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py:667: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'deathcount' was never awaited
  self._ready.clear()
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

[Весь код](https://pastebin.com/sdUQ4W9J)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы совсем неправильно используете `asyncio`. И `deathcount` совсем не асинхронная. Тут серьезный пробел и нет смысла пересказывать, как работает и использовать `asyncio`.

Если коротко, то первая ошибка возникает, потому, что `async` функцию нужно вызывать используя `await` из цикла созданного с помощью `asyncio.run` или подобным образом.

Вторая ошибка (после попытки исправить) возникает из-за того, что попытка запустить asyncio цикл, неправильная. Смотрите как это делает `asyncio.run` [тут](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/asyncio/runners.py).

Можно, конечно, подружить обычные потоки и `asyncio`, но я думаю вам не это нужно.
Создайте обычный `QThread` по аналогии с `WorkThread` и в нем вызывайте `deathcount` без всяких `async/await`.

Если вы хотите именно `asyncio`, то нужно задать отдельный сфокусированный вопрос, т.к. ответ будет довольно обширный.

Comment: Понял, спасибо. Просто проблема в том, что я хочу вместе со всем этим запускать **Discord**-бота, который как раз таки построен на `asyncio`. Как мне тогда быть?

Comment: У discrod бота есть основной скрипт или класс, там где запускается `asyncio.run` напрямую или через api библиотеки, которую вы используете. Так вот, вам нужно ту функцию, которая запускает цикл обработи `asyncio` запустить не в главном потоке, а в потоке, который вы создадите с помощью `QThread`. Чтоб что-то конкретное советовать, нужен отдельный вопрос, с кодом и т.д.

Comment: Звучит сложно.. :\
Завтра задам вопрос, спасибо