# Ошибка при выполнение функции в telebot pytnon

Tags: python, telebot, telethon

Использую бибилиотеку telebot в python чтобы управлять ботом. До этого все функции из других файлов запускались, а тут появилась проблемка. Представим что юзер нажимает старт и функция запускается

```
import TelegramNumberChecker.Telegram_checker as tgcheck
import telebot

def start_bot():
    @bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
    def handler_start(message):
        inputdata = '7900000000'
        telegram_phone = tgcheck.get_names(phone_number=inputdata)
```

Эта функция выглядит +- так: (чтобы не раскрывать весь код)

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, errors, events, sync
from telethon.tl.types import InputPhoneContact
from telethon import functions
from getpass import getpass

API_ID = ''
API_HASH = ''
PHONE_NUMBER = ''


def get_names(phone_number): 
    #client connect session
    client = TelegramClient(PHONE_NUMBER, API_ID, API_HASH)
    client.connect()
    #дальше идёт код
```

Сообственно говоря после того как я запустил бота и нажал start всё что до этой функции оно может обработать, а на ней вылазит ошибка, при том что если эту функцию запустить отдельно, то-есть не подключать к боту, то она работает:

```
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 639, in get_event_loop
    raise RuntimeError('There is no current event loop in thread %r.'
RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'WorkerThread2'.
```

Может ли это быть из-за того что я использую 2 библиотеки telebot и telethon?

Comment: Ну, две библиотеки уже не хорошо, если они обе про ботов телеграма )  И ещё может быть несовместимость с конкретной версией питона. И с платформой windows тоже может быть несовместимость.

Comment: А вот такое решение не пробовали https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/787832/260769

Comment: Находил похожее, но мне не понятно что с этим делать

Comment: Ну просто написать в том месте, где у вас бот стартует. Как у вас выглядит блок `if __name__ == '__main__':`, если он есть? )

Comment: if __name__ == '__main__': отсутствует, запускается сразу функция start_bot(), а так же указано bot.polling(none_stop = True)

Comment: добавил перед start_bot() loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop) - ничего не поменялось

Comment: Судя по всему цикл событий отсутсвует как раз по причине работы двух библиотек, по идее вполне должно хватать одной из них. Предполагаю что вместо `bot.polling(none_stop = True)` следует использовать `bot.infinity_polling()` Еще я бы убрал вложенность в start_bot(), по идее бот сам подхватывает в нужное время указанные хэндлеры. Возможно будет полезно https://habr.com/ru/post/580408/

Comment: Данил спасибо, но инфинити просто скипает ошибки, я посидел и разобрался с @CrazyElf вариантом и он в итоге сработал, добавьте эти 2 строки как вариант ответа, я посчитаю правильным

Comment: @Kowl Если помог в точности тот ответ по ссылке, то тогда мне видимо нужно сделать ваш вопрос дубликатом того вопроса. А если всё же есть какие-то отличия, то вы можете сами дать ответ на свой вопрос, указав сработавший вариант )

Comment: Отличий нет, просто 2 строки кода надо было поставить перед client = TelegramClient(PHONE_NUMBER, API_ID, API_HASH) и тогда код заработал, перед этим импортировав asyncio. Спасибо за совет, дело в том я изначально не туда ставил эти строки, а ночью перед сном прям в мозг ударило и всё получилось

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Спасибо [@CrazyElf](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/260769/crazyelf). Скинул уже существующий ответ на вопрос [тык](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/787832/260769)

2 строки кода вставить перед начало выполнения функции

```
def get_names(phone_number): 
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    #client connect session
    client = TelegramClient(PHONE_NUMBER, API_ID, API_HASH)
    client.connect()
    #дальше идёт код
```